# MSDN Basic Rss for Windows Phone error

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

First, sorry if my english is not perfect.
I tried this tutorial from MSDN 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh487167%28v=vs.92%29.aspx

and I got this error message:

The type 'converter:RssTextTrimmer' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.

I downloaded the sample files from msdn and I got the same error. 
I am new to C# and Windows Phone.

I hope someone could help me. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're specifying the correct xmlns value for "converter", based on your project's namespace.

From the example on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh487167%28v=vs.92%29.aspx):

> 8.Set up the RssTextTrimmer class as a converter by double-clicking **App.xaml** in **Solution Explorer**, and adding the following code inside of
>   the <**Application.Resources**> tag:
>
> `<converter:RssTextTrimmer
>    xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:sdkRSSReaderCS" x:Key="RssTextTrimmer"
>    />`
>
> Where **sdkRSSReaderCS** is the name of your project's namespace.

Comment: I am specifying the correct xmlns value (sdkRSSReaderCS was replaced with the name of my project's namespace) . If I don't do that, I get another error message.

Comment: I don't know why, but after I cut and paste the same values it works. Anyway, thank you for your answer

Comment: Do you still have what the original value was?  You might've gotten a typo in there that was hard to spot.  Glad it works now.